# Changing state of custom Ribbon controls

Tags: content-editor, ribbon

I have created a custom ribbon button (Large Button) and a text field (Small Input Box). I can disable/enable these controls just fine when clicking an item (by the `CommandState QueryState()` override).

However, when clicking the button, I need to set some text to the text field and disable the button, and I haven't found any ways to do this.

How can I set the state (enable/disable, text) of other ribbon controls from a custom button?

Comment: You'll need to limit your question to a single question (I recommend creating a new one with your second question; they are both good questions!).

Comment: Have you considered building this in SPE? It could be way less complicated. https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/content-editor#ribbon

Comment: @DanSinclair I've split this into two questions now. The other one's here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17279/prevent-custom-ribbon-button-from-redirecting-to-new-item

Answer (score 1):

You can change the text of the button by overriding the following method:

```
public override string GetHeader(CommandContext context, string header)
{
    //Build some logic here
    return "Modified header text";
}
```

Moreover, you can override the tooltip text by overriding this:

```
public override string GetToolTip(CommandContext context, string tooltip)
{
    return base.GetToolTip(context, tooltip);
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean the text of the button. I meant I want to change the text on the Small Input Box _from_ the button.